# CORS: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49531/Access/Authenticate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:31775' is therefore not allowed access.**

I am flushing request coming with `OPTIONS`. Request returns with code 200, however I am still getting this error.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to do is to adding a token to `header` from client side and server side. Once client has been authenticated, token is added to request from server. From next request initiated from client, this token is sent by javascript.

Comment: Try to enable CORS in your server ``http://localhost:49531``

Comment: You need to add the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=<CLIENT DOMAIN>" on the server side.

Comment: You need to respond the preflight request with a proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers. An additional `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` might also be required if the request contains `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header.

Comment: Would this have any security concerns?

Comment: Yes, there are security concerns. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-angularjs)