# React + Express Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I know that their is a similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956421/cors-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check) however its not specific to express, with react as the front end.

I get this error.

[image]

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/users/auth/github' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8001' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

My goal is to console.log the response.

Here is how my express app.js is set up

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
var models = require('./models/');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
// const allowOrigin = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*'

// CORS Middleware





if (!process.env.PORT) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

if (!process.env.PORT) {
  console.log('[api][port] 8000 set as default')
  console.log('[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set as default')
} else {
  console.log('[api][node] Loaded ENV vars from .env file')
  console.log(`[api][port] ${process.env.PORT}`)
  console.log(`[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN}`)
}

// app.use(cors({
//   origin: process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN,
//   credentials:true,
//   allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, origin, X-Custom-Header',
//   methods: 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',

// }));




require('./config/passport-github');
require('./config/passport');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 84,
  resave: false

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 

const isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    next();
    console.log('this works');
  }else{
   res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/signIn');
  }
}
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',  true);
  res.header(' preflightContinue', false)
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
  next();
});

app.use('/api/users', userRoute );
app.use('/api/posts', isAuthenticated,  postRoute );
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user

  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});




models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```

Front end

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {compose} from 'redux';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import ourStyles from '../styles/ourStyles';
import github from './github/github';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import { history } from '../components/layout/Navbar';
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: ""
        }


    }



    fetchData = () => { // error happens here

        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_GITHUB_SIGNIN, { 
            method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',          
                },    
            })
            .then( (res)=> {
                console.log(res)
                // history.push('/dashboard')   
            })
            .catch( (err) => {

            })

    }


    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;

        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            return (<Redirect to='/dashboard' />);
        }
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Grid container justify="center" spacing={44}>
                    <Grid item sm={7}>
                        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                            <Chip
                                label="Sign In with Github"
                                clickable
                                onClick={this.fetchData}
                                avatar={< Avatar alt = "Natacha" src = "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/9919?s=280&v=4" />}
                                // href={process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_GITHUB_SIGNIN}
                                component="a"
                                className={classes.chip}/>



                            <Chip
                                label="Sign Up with E-Mail"
                                clickable
                                href="/signUp"
                                component="a"
                                className={classes.chip}/>
                        </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    token: state.user.getToken,
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
    redirectTo: state.user.redirectTo
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
});
// export default withStyles(styles)(Navbar);
export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withStyles(ourStyles))(Home);
```

extra code

**routes/users**

```
router.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github') );

router.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/'}),
  function(req, res, done) {

     console.log(`session ${req.session.passport.user} `); // renders the user id
      const user = req.session.passport.user;
        if(user){   
          req.login(user, err => {
            const data = {
                id: req.session.passport.user   
            };
            models.User.findOne({
              where: {
                id: data.id,
              },
            }).then(user => {
              const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id  }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
              res.cookie("jwt", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10*1000*60*60*24)});
              res.status(200).send({
                auth: true,
                token: token,
                message: 'user found & logged in',
              });
            })
          // res.cookie("jwt", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10*1000*60*60*24)});
          // res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/dashboard')   

          });

        } else if(user == null) {
            console.log(info.message);
            res.status(403).send(info.message);
        }

  });
```

Comment: did you use cors to backend?

Comment: i will post full app.js code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: this doesn't really help, i went through that multiple times.

Comment: If you look at the console the option request used to know the allowed origins return an 500 error did you try to know why ?

Comment: Just include cors before your routes.

Comment: Why have you commented app.use(cors()); ?

Comment: because it does not work :(, but i will figure this out.

Comment: Uncomment it and check the response to OPTIONS request in chrome dev tools or Fiddler. Your error says that response to OPTIONS request is not 200 OK, thats why browser is not allowing CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Add `cors` to your backend like this (above your endpoints):

```
app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that React is sending to the API
    'exposedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that you are sending back to React
    'origin': '*',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    'preflightContinue': false
}));
```

Comment: i still get `from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled`

Comment: ill upvote because this is actually something i haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you get 308 response code in the packet then try adding or removing '/' at the end of your endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use(cors());
```

You have imported cors but you have used it.

Comment: i did but i get `Access to fetch at 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&client_id=285bda995ab97d093821' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/api/users/auth/github') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`